# I have fitted an equation using GAMs (generalized additive models) in R using model1 <- mgcv::gam( x1..xn). How do i get the equation format?

Tags: r, regression, mgcv

```
library(mgcv)
model1 <- gam(x1,x2.....,xn)
```

I can get the partial dependency plots with the predictors and can also use the predict function for model prediction. But I want to publish the model in a Research journal, hence i will be needing the model in an equation format to be published in a paper so that someone reading the article can use the model to predict some element as the R file cannot be shared with the journal.
Any help to get the GAM model as an equation like f(x1,x2..xn) = intercept+ coef1 * s(x1)+...+ coefn * s(xn).
and what the the exact mathematical function of the spline function?

Fitting a non-linear model GAM shows good fit but unable to provide me with an equation.

Comment: "hence i will be needing the model in an equation format" No, you don't. You can share your data and code and you can even share the fitted model object as an RDS file. Basically, do the same as researchers using other machine learning approaches that don't yield a parametric model.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of these models is that we typically don't have the mathematical equation for the fitted function. Of course, at some level we do have a mathematical equation but it will be written in terms of the basis expansion of the smooth covariate(s).

What we don't have is an equation of the form

$$
\hat{y}_i = \alpha + \beta_1 s_1(x_{1i}) + \beta_2 s_2(x_{2i}) + \cdots
$$
as that isn't even the model that you fitted - you are not multiplying a smooth function ($s_j()$) by a model parameter $\beta_j$. What you typically fit with a GAM is something like:

$$
\hat{y}_i = \alpha + \sum_{k=1}^{K_1} { \beta_{1k} b_1(x_{1i}) } + \sum_{k=1}^{K_2} { \beta_{2k} b_2(x_{2i}) } + \cdots
$$

where the $b_j$ are basis function of a particular type (low-rank thinplate regression spline, cubic regression spline, b spline, ...) and their associated coefficient ($\beta_{jk}$) of which there will be $K_j$ such basis functions and coefficient pairs per smooth function $s_j()$.

The pseudo-code you show (`gam(x1, x2, ..., xn)`) simply doesn't make any sense as a valid GAM model fitted with `gam()`: if should be of the form

```r
gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + ... + s(xn),
    data = foo, method = "REML", family = fam, ...)
```

so it's not even clear what form of GAM you fitted.

Options for sharing your model are:

1. Share the original data and the code used to fit the model, plus any specific version info for the software you used.
2. Share the fitted model by serializing it to disk as an RDS object via `saveRDS()` plus code to show how to use it to predict (this is actually not such a simple thing as factors need to have the right levels etc, if you have a more complex model).
3. You could pre-compute what is know as the $L_p$ matrix or linear predictor matrix for your model. Say you have a simple model of the form:

   ```
   m <- gam(y ~ s(x1), data = foo, ...)
   ```

   then you would generate new values for `x1` over a fine grid (as fine a grid as you would need for the practical and scientific purposes you might want to use the model at, and certainly no finer than the precision of `x1`), and create the $L_p$ matrix via the `predict()` method:

   ```
   newd <- data.frame(x1 = seq(min(x1), max(x1), by = 0.1)) # for example
   Xp <- predict(m, newdata = newd, type = "lpmatrix")
   ```

   You will also need to extract the model coefficients

   ```
   betas <- coef(m)
   ```

   And save all of these (`newd`, `Xp` and `betas`) to disk via `saveRDS()`.

   The new user can then assign each of the values in their data to a row in `newd` (to the closest value in `newd`), extract those same rows from `Xp`, and then generate predictions/fitted values via

   ```
   fit <- Xp[want, ] %*% betas
   ```

   which would yield predicted values on the link scale, which you could transform to the response scale if needed by application of the inverse of the relevant link function.
4. There's also possibly something you might be able to do with Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML) but I am not familiar with this functionality in R or for {mgcv} GAMs in particular.

Which of these methods works best will depend on the intended use of readers of your paper, with option 1 being the most broadly useful way to do this.

Comment: model2 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3) + s(x4) + s(x5) + s(x6) , data = mydata, method = "REML")
this commend was used for modelling, pardon for not  mentioning it properly in the question.  mgcv pakage 1.8-41 was used. And RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium" Release (7d165dcfc1b6d300eb247738db2c7076234f6ef0, 2022-12-03) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36  was used.